# Unable to post FormData via Ajax with Laravel (405 Error)

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel

*Straight to the point*: The end goal here is to be able to submit multiple forms with one button in **Laravel**. One of the forms contains a file upload field.

When attempting to make the Ajax Call, i'm receiving a `405 Method Not Allowed` error. Looking through several Stack Overflow questions, I have managed to narrow it down to two options (processData, contentType) in the Ajax Call below.

My issue is, If I remove both of these I then receive an Illegal Invocation error on the `new Formdata($this)`. So, how would I submit a file upload whilst still keeping it an Ajax Call?

**The Ajax Call**

```
// Submit all forms

        $.each(forms, function(form){
            formData = new FormData(form);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: formData,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('Form submitted');
                },
                error: function(x, h, r){
                    console.log(x, h, r);
                }
            })
        });
```

**The route function that the forms are targetting**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Save clinic initially
    $clinic = Clinic::find($id);
    $clinic->update($request->all());

    // If image is present, save it and update it in the database table
    if ($request->file('clinic_logo')) {
        $file = $request->file('clinic_logo');
        $fileExtension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filePath = '/img/profile_images/' . $request->get('clinic_name') . "." . $fileExtension;

        // Save Image
        $file->move(
            base_path() . '/public/img/profile_images/', $request->get('clinic_name') . "." . $fileExtension
        );

        // Update database table
        $clinic->logo = $filePath;
        $clinic->save();
    }

    $data = [
        'clinic' => $clinic,
        'categories' => Category::where('approved', 1)->pluck('name', 'id')
    ];

    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Clinic has been successfully edited.');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Screenshot of my Chrome Console with Options**
[image]

**Screenshot of my Chrome Console without options**
[image]

**Update 1**

The actual routing works fine. If I remove both of those Ajax options, the forms post and the data updates correctly, just without the file upload. If I use a regular submit button in the form, everything works fine - including upload data. Route is a resource controller as below;

```
Route::resource('clinics', 'ClinicController');
```

**Update 2**

So now at least, I know *why* i'm getting the `405 method not allowed` errors. Setting `processData: false` screws up the request data resulting in Laravel not understanding both the `csrf_token` and the `_method field` - resulting in `Method not allowed`. Still not sure how to fix this, just thought the extra info might help.

**Update 3**

Routes list, as requested.

```
|        | POST      | clinics                           | clinics.store         | App\Http\Controllers\ClinicController@store                            | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | clinics                           | clinics.index         | App\Http\Controllers\ClinicController@index                            | web          |
|        | PUT       | clinics/approve/{id}              | clinics.approve       | App\Http\Controllers\ClinicController@approve                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | clinics/create                    | clinics.create        | App\Http\Controllers\ClinicController@create                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | clinics/request                   |                       | App\Http\Controllers\ClinicController@request                          | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | clinics/{clinic}                  | clinics.update        | App\Http\Controllers\ClinicController@update                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | clinics/{clinic}                  | clinics.show          | App\Http\Controllers\ClinicController@show                             | web          |
|        | DELETE    | clinics/{clinic}                  | clinics.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\ClinicController@destroy                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | clinics/{clinic}/edit             | clinics.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\ClinicController@edit                             | web          |
```

The forms are pretty big, but they're built using the form model binding pattern [found here](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#form-model-binding).

```
{!! Form::model($clinic, ['route' => ['clinics.update', $clinic], 'method' => 'PUT', 'files' => true, 'class' => 'multi-part-form']) !!}
```

Comment: Show your route function.

Comment: Updated with route function

Comment: @NiketJoshi not in the JS file, no - but one is included with the form if that helps.

Comment: sorry @Lewis by mistake i comment on that.

Comment: I think what @KannanK want to ask is "does your router function allows this route (`/clinics/:id`) can be took with post method ?". I'm don't know Laravel but it's possible that you have somewhere in your code `Route::get(/clinics/:id)`where it should be `Route::post(...)`

Comment: show your route which present in routes.php

Comment: Added route information to the question. It posts fine without those ajax options - however, the file upload information isn't saved. If I use a regular submit button in the form, everything works fine - including upload data.

Comment: Please also provide the HTML code where you defining the form and the output of the console command `php artisan route:list`, but only the `clinics` portion.

Comment: @Konafets Updated.

Answer (score -2):

When dealing with ajax with attachment. Implying the `FormData() function` in your javascript will not easily bind your file attachments. you need to separately bind your attachments into something like this.

```
formData = new FormData(form);
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

i hope this will help you

Comment: From [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData): An HTML `<form>` element — when specified, the `FormData` object will be populated with the form's current keys/values using the name property of each element for the keys and their submitted value for the values. **It will also encode file input content**

Comment: Even if that wasn't the case, I don't see what it has with the server giving a Method Not Allowed error message.

Comment: since this is ajax, try to add additional key for the update process since you are using a resource route. UPDATE record is a POST method with input '_method' : "PATCH"

Comment: merge your formData with the _method : "PATCH" on the data property of ajax. :)

Comment: Hi @KennethSunday, thanks for your reply. I tried your solution of passing the method separately as appended data, however it is still affected by `processData: false` - it looks like using this confuses Laravel and it can't understand the fields being sent.

Comment: so it is now working by removing the processData property ? :)

Comment: No, that results in the other error mentioned in the question.

Comment: in that case, try to rewrite your route, instead of using a resource , try to break your route just to validate where your error came from.